How to make a minimap section header in HTML files?
VS Code introduced minimap section headers and provided an example of how to use it in TypeScript files. However, I'm unsure how to enable this feature for HTML files. Can anyone help with this?

I tried both of these:
<!--MARK: stuff-->
<!--//#region stuff-->

But neither worked.

Did you try <!-- MARK: stuff -->? Note the colon after MARK!

@md2perpe yes it was a typo , i edited the question

Within HTML (.html file):
<!--
    MARK: Stuff
-->

Within HTML (.php file):
<!--
    //region Stuff
 -->

Javascript:
<script>
    //region Stuff
</script> 

CSS (within  tags in an .html)
/*
    //region Stuff
*/

CSS (.css file)
/*
    MARK: Stuff
*/

PHP:
<?php
     //MARK: Stuff
?>

The main thing is that //region or //MARK have to be on their own line.  As noted, there's likely more at play here if this doesn't work for you, but as of the initial release and its documentation, this has been found to work.

you didnt even test your answer , HTML and CSS do not work

I think there's more at play here than meets the eye:  It's not as straight forward as "You didn't even test".   I discovered that VSCode isn't handling .php and .html files the same way inside  tags.  My answers work for me inside a .php but for an .html I had to switch to  as you suggested.  However, there was still the variance on CSS where your suggestion did not work for me.  But it looks like you found a solution that works for you so I hope I was able to help guide you there.

I think I just figured out your complaint, @AymenHmani.  When you referenced CSS, I think you're referring to a .css file, rather than CSS within an HTML.  In that case, your edit is correct.  However, your question was regarding HTML files, not CSS files and so I answered appropriately.  I'll update my answer for differentiating between the two and the markup to accommodate as required.

To make a minimap section header in HTML files do this:
<!-- #region MARK: Name -->
<!-- #endregion -->

In CSS (both file and HTML tag):
/* #region MARK: Name */
/* #endregion */

That is if you want to create regions as well. If you simply want headers do this:
HTML
<!-- MARK: Name -->

CSS
/* MARK: Name */

Unfortunately as of now section headers are nor created for regions in HTML and in CSS and you have to use MARK: to achieve this.
I have filed a bug report on this here.
In JS they though, they work fine:
Regions with section headers:
// #region Name
// #endregion

Just section headers:
// MARK: Name

However only region folding works in HTML script tags. Nor MARK: Name nor #region Name produce section headers in the minimap.
